# Bootstrap Collapsible panel content reset to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have panel which contains huge scrollable data, once scroll down the content and collapse the panel/come from other page then data is setting to top, scroll down remains same, its not resetting to top position.
I have tried below code but no luck
please anybody help me to get resolve this

```
 $('#techAssmnt').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {

       //setTimeout(function(){
       //$("techAssmnt").animate({ 
          //scrollTop: $('#page-top-wrapper').offset().top 
           //}, 800, 'swing', 
           //function() {});  
          //},500);

        //$( "div.assessmentMainDiv" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        //$("#Section_1").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

         $("#Section_1").animate({ scrollTop: 
       $('#templateCollapse3262').offset().top }, 800, 'swing', function() {
            });  

         //$("div.assessmentMainDiv").css(["top","1px", "left","0", 'right':'0','bottom':'0', 'overflow':'auto']);

         $("div.assessmentMainDiv").css({
               'top' : '1px',
               'left' : '0',
               'right' : '0',
               'bottom' : '0',
               'overflow' : 'auto'
            });
        });
```

Below code also I have tried

```
$('#techAssmnt').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
       //alert("sasdas")
        var panelHeadingHeight = $('.panel-heading').height();
        var animationSpeed = 500; // animation speed in milliseconds
        var currentScrollbarPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        var topOfPanelContent = $(e.target).offset().top;

        if ( currentScrollbarPosition >  topOfPanelContent - panelHeadingHeight) {
            $("#Section_1").animate({ scrollTop: topOfPanelContent - panelHeadingHeight }, animationSpeed);
        }  
    });
```

https://www.bootply.com/8bGdJgkmUv

please check this.. In the first panel there is huge content and also scrollable.. Once I open and scroll the content then I close/hide/toggle the panel but content is not all reset to top

Comment: Can you add working fiddle?, so it will help another members to helps you.

Comment: @NiravJoshi https://www.bootply.com/8bGdJgkmUv please check this.. In the first panel there is huge content and also scrollable.. Once I open and scroll the content then I close/hide/toggle the panel but content is not all reset to top

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this jquery

```
$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).children().scrollTop(0);
});
```

[Working Snippet](https://www.bootply.com/KHIn1igKET)

Comment: Im using it in mobile.. Its not working.. In your example its working fine

Comment: Have you made proper code for it? if yes than make snippet of it.. let me check it again

Comment: I can't make snippet of my code bcoz its binding dynamically from web api.. My code is exactly same as your working snippet only but I dont know why its not working

Comment: Than you have to debug it because it is working fine.. also i checked it in localhost working fine for me